# Integrating css into Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My problem is simple but I'm new to `jquery` and `css` so I don't really know what I'm doing. I have a css file `style.css` and this is what's in it.

```
keyword {
font-size: 12px;
color: #0000FF;
}

stringWord {
font-size: 12px;
color: #ff6a00;
}
```

I'm trying to change text inside of a text area so here is where that is declared.

```
<div class="DivWithScroll" id="my_text" contenteditable="true" 
     onkeypress="return myKeyPress(event)" onkeydown="return onKeyDown(event)">
```

In my `jquery` code I want it to go to the `css file` of `keyword` and change the color of the text.

This is what I have so far but it's not working properly

```
for (var i = 0; i < reservedKeyWords.length; i++) {
    if ( lastWordTyped == reservedKeyWords[i] ) {
        console.log(lastWordTyped + "::" + reservedKeyWords[i]);

        $('DivToScroll').css("keyword");
        return;
    }
}
 `
```

Like I said I'm new to all of this so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're completely misunderstanding CSS.  You need to learn about class names and selectors.

Comment: you want to change text inside an area, what is the css for then? dont get your question actually. what do you want to do exactly? maybe the jquery documentation would be a good start.

Comment: You should create separate CSS classes with the colors you want.  Then you manipulate the classes not the actual CSS.

Comment: I just want to use the css to actually change the color of the word, I don't have to do it no, I was just under the impression that it was the "proper thing to do"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.css('keyword')` use `.addClass('keyword')`.

Answer (score 0):

Also note that your jQuery selector is targeting 'DivToScroll' rather than 'DivWithScroll' and you may want to change the jQuery selector to be

```
$('#my_text')
```

to reference the div by ID.